# Can't send authorized request to Sonarqube api with JavaScript fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, sonarqube

I try to send api request to sonarqube with fetch function but I receive a 401 response. My request works well on postman but does not with JavaScript. While I retrieved the same headers as on postman.

I set mode to no-cors but it did not work.

```
fetch('https://MYSONARQUBE/api/project_branches/list?project=MYPROJECT', {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic MjE0NWE0NDA4ZDlmNjE3NzY0MTA4N2Y1ZjAxY2U4MzU3MGUyMTU5Mzo=",
              },
              mode: 'no-cors'
            }) 
              .then(function(res) {
                // make the promise be rejected if we didn't get a 2xx response
                if (res.status >= 200 && res.status <= 299) {
                  return res.json();
                } else {
                  return res.status;
                }
              })
```

I expect a full JSON response like on postman but got `res.status = 0` (I don't know why) and a 401 on Network tab of google chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you sending the same network request compaired to Postman? You can try to use a tool like Fiddler.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes I'm sure, I took header from Postman and request is the same. Request works with curl too. Thank's I will look.